# Pytest Patching Sleep On Certain Condition

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing tests using Pytest and Python 3.6. My tests use an ENV var called online, which I use to determine whether the tests will hit the real web service or whether it will just be playback.

I want to patch sleep when the tests are not online for all the tests. When the tests are in online mode, dont patch.  Is there a way to do this on pytest? My initial thought was to use a fixture that uses the env var to monkeypatch or not.

I am not sure how to go about with this?

Comment: Using a fixture that does that seems to be ok - have you tried it? Can you show what does not work for you?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, just looking at some tests that are written with unittest and vcrpy. The old test would patch time sleep if it was running in offline mode. Was wondering the best way to do it globally once versus per method using pytest.monkeypatch

Comment: If you use a fixture, "globally" would just mean to use a session-scoped fixture, otherwise you use a function-scoped fixture. If the environment does not change during the test, you can just use a global autouse fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use an autouse fixture. The standard way is to use `mock.patch` to mock the function:

```py
from unittest import mock
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_sleep():
    if "ONLINE" in os.environ and os.environ["ONLINE"] == "1":
        with mock.patch("time.sleep"):
            yield
    else:
        yield
```

In this case the function will be patched in each test, and the patch reverted after each test. If you use `autouse=True`, the fixture will be invoked automatically in all tests, otherwise you have to reference it in the tests.

If you know that your environment cannot change during the test, you can use a session-scoped fixture that is invoked only once in the test session:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def patch_sleep():
   ...
```

In this case, `time.sleep` will be patched before all tests run, and the patch reverted after all tests have finished.

If you don't want to use `unittest.patch`, you can use the `pytest-mock` plugin, which provides the `mocker` fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_sleep(mocker):
    if "ONLINE" in os.environ and os.environ["ONLINE"] == "1":
        mocker.patch("time.sleep")
        yield
    else:
        yield
```

You can also use `monkeypatch`, though that is not the usual way for patching a function:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_sleep(monkeypatch):
    def dont_sleep(sec):
        pass

    if "ONLINE" in os.environ and os.environ["ONLINE"] == "1":
        monkeypatch.setattr(time, "sleep", dont_sleep)
        yield
    else:
        yield
```

Comment: this makes perfect sense. So now I just include that as a decorator over my tests

````@patch_sleep
def test_something````

or will it be 
````def test_something(patch_sleep):````

Comment: If you use `autouse=True`, you don't need it - I added a note in the answer.